# How to concatenate a char* and a string?

Tags: c++

My problem is that I get an error when trying to add hard-coded text, `"334 "` before my decoded user input:

```
 received = buf;
    if(strncmp(buf, "334 ", 4) == 0){
        decoding(received.c_str() + 4, strlen(buf + 4), buf);
        received = "334 " + buf;
    }
```

Here is the error I get:

> invalid operands of types 'const char[5] and 'char[300] to binary 'operator+'

Comment: You should make up your mind whether you are trying to write C or C++.

Comment: Use `strncat()` or `strcat()`

Comment: You're attempting to add two *pointers*, and that doesn't make much sense. It would make much more sense if you use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for all string variables in your code.

Comment: I don't need to use std::string because I have using namespace std; at the top of my code.

Comment: @ms01249 When people say "use `std::string`" they mean use the standard string type. Whether you use `std::string` or `string` with `using namespace std;`, it's the same thing. People aren't saying that you should use `std::string` instead of `string`. Though, that would also be good advice. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: What type is `received`? If `received` is a pointer, `received = buf;` will make `received` point to `buf`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It must be `std::string`, since it has a `c_str()` method.

Comment: Let me rephrase my comment: You should use [the standard library string class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: @Barmar The code doesn't compile, so we don't know that for sure.

Comment: received is a string, buf is a char array

Comment: received = buf; works perfectly fine and decodes the output for me. But I want to add "334 " to the beginning of that decoded text.

Comment: To preform concatenation with `operator+` you need an intervening `std::string`. You can't directly add `char*` or `char[]` to concatenate. Using `received` would work. Try `received = "334"; received += buf;`.

Comment: Your logic looks bogus, if `buff` starts with "334 " put `"334  " + buff` into received (and buff srtarts with "334 " already)

Comment: I skip this because I am decoding more than one message. I skip "334 " and "330 " to decode the desired string.

Comment: great advice @FrançoisAndrieux ! That worked!

Answer (score 4):

`std::string` has a constructor that takes a `char *`, so you can create a `std::string` from `buf` like this:

```
std::string buf_str(buf);
```

---

From [**cplusplus.com**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/)'s list of `std::string` constructors:

> `string (const char* s);`
>
> Copies the null-terminated character sequence (C-string) pointed by s.

Comment: buf is a char array with a set max size of 300. I set received = buf before I decode, skip the first 4 characters, in this case, "334 " and decode. Then I set that new decoded string to received = buf; again. I want to add the "334 " back on after I decode.

Comment: I'd suggest using the [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) explanation instead as it explains things a little more thoroughly (and is usually better than cplusplus.com from what I've seen).

Comment: @scohe001 I agree, but in this case, I thought the example from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) was simpler, showing more clearly that there's a `std::string` constructor that can take a `char *`.

Comment: cplusplus.com trades a bit of accuracy for a lower barrier to entry. When preaching to the newb, that lower barrier can be very important. Face it, a lot of the time cppreference looks like Martian to the uninitiated. Right off the bat, the new programmer has to figure out what a  `basic_string` is. Shouldn't be hard, but why is it even necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if that can suit you but you can consider using the [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/) class so that you can merge the text variables as:

```
stringstream longone;
string text;
longone << received << "334 ";
string=longone.str()
```